# Hypothesis test for population rather than for sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences

I have a set of data for companies in a certain industry. The data set spans two consecutive years, 2000 and 2001.

Let's say I have 100 unique companies in the dataset and I calculate average service time for each company and for each year.

How do I test whether the average waiting time for company x in 2001 is less than the average waiting time for company x in 2000?

The data set contains all service transactions performed by company x in 2000 and 2001, and this is what confuses me. The way I understand hypothesis test is that you test the null hypothesis using sample mean. However, with this data I have the population mean so what does it mean when your professor ask you to test whether the average service time in 2001 is less than the average service time in 2000 using "simple mean comparison test such as t-statistic"?

Comment: [Please add the 'self-study' tag] It's like trying to check if your younger brother is really taller than you. You just compare the values! If you *truly have the populations about which you wish to make some statements* about how the averages compare, you simply look at the two averages. Is one less than the other? But since this is something you've been given to do by a professor, *why not ask him what he intended you to do with populations rather than samples*? I am sure his response will provide more illumination than our guesses as to what he was looking for.

Comment: @Glen_b Exactly! this what I was thinking. I already have the real numbers.. what do I need to compare? but I'll ask the professor about this to be sure I didn't miss anything. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever there's a case where people seem determined to insist on some kind of test - and thereby a probabilistic sampling argument - it usually turns out to be because they want their inference to apply *outside* the populations at hand, in some way. If that's not the case, then the sampling we'd normally do is in order to make inferences about the unknown population quantities of interest but if those quantities are actually known, there's nothing to do, since you can immediately see their values.

Comment: I think the question "test whether the average service time in 2001 is less than the average service time in 2000" is not asking you for the specific companies you have in your sample but for all companies of that industry during that time period.

Comment: You are really comparing *processes* not companies. The total  number of service times observed in a certain year (even if that represents *all* services offered by that company that year)  is a sample (from the process) not a population. I see no problems here.

Comment: I bet you are supposed to treat the transactions set as a sample. Yes, it is all transactions that were performed, it is not all the transaction that could have been performed by that company, usually. So, it's a sample.